# "Up" script for moving up directories quickly

Tags: console, bash

A long time ago I created a script for moving up directories very quickly in the command line using the command `up`. You can find usage notes [here](https://github.com/joezeng/up/).

It's a very simple script with just 8 lines of source code, as follows:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    cd ..
else
    for i in `seq 1 $1`;
    do
        cd ..
    done
fi
```

I've never personally had any problems with it since I made it and started using it myself — but are there any accidental or malicious inputs (particularly with the blind injection of `$1`) that might cause this to do something bad that I'm not aware of?

Given that the `up` command isn't used for anything in any command line I'm aware of, I'd like to promote more widespread usage of this script file so that people can type `up` instead of `cd ..` all the time, saving three keystrokes (or more if they want to move up more directories) for a very common operation.

Comment: zsh: `..`. Also, `...`, `....`, `.....`, ...

Comment: @naught101: that's why I tagged this question `bash`. :P

Comment: Nice approach, but I simply used `alias f='cd ..;';alias ff='cd ..;cd ..;'alias fff='cd ..;cd ..;cd ..;';alias ffff='cd ..;cd ..;cd ..;cd ..;'; alias fffff='cd ..;cd ..;cd ..';cd ..;cd ..;` in `bashrc` because there's only so many times you'd want to go up and the "f" key is easily accessible. Just a matter of typing "f" a few times and then hit enter instead of type `up 5`. The "f" stands for "fall" because from childhood, I considered `cd dirName` to be "climbing" directories and `cd ..` to be falling from a climbed directory.

Comment: @Nav: if you were doing that, why not use `cd ../..` for `ff`? You iterated them independently by hand.

Comment: I've been satisfied with just `cd` to take me home. Since all the files I own and work on are within there. And usually getting back to working files are less than four or five tab-competes deep.  Though more commonly `cd ~/where/ever/`. [Just speaking generally about my personal cd usage.]

Comment: @JoeZ. Nice approach. Will use.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your recommendation is to define `alias up=". path/to/up"` so that when you type `up 3`, it expands to `. up 3`.  However, since you want to take an optional argument and affect the state of the current shell, I think you would be better off defining a **shell function** instead.

As it turns out, the `[ -z "$1" ]` **special case is not necessary**, since `seq 1` just expands to `1`.

You end up executing ***n* separate `cd ..` commands** for `up n`.  This leads to a usability bug: [`cd -` or `cd $OLDPWD`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-cd), which normally take you back to the previous directory, don't work the way I expect.

Suggested solution:

```
up() {
    cd $(for i in $(seq 1 $1) ; do echo -n ../ ; done)
}
```

Comment: So defining `up` in that way makes a literal `cd -` useless? Or were you expecting `up -` to work as `cd -` as well?

Comment: @JoeZ. the former - `cd -` will return you back **one** level after calling `up n` with `n > 1`. This causes an issue if you want to get back to where you were before you called `up n`.  Concating the command into a single `cd` will preserve the functionality.

Comment: This is an extremely elegant solution and should be the accepted answer.  Kudos.

Answer (score 22):

This is a decent concept, but by looping on the `cd` you loose some of the value of the `$OLDPWD` function in the shell. For example, I often use the special construct `cd -` in a shell, and that changes directory to the one you were in before.

Your code will make that impossible.

I would instead recommend that you instead build up a chain of `../` string values, like `../../../../` for 4 directories, and then just call `cd` once, which will preserve the `cd -` function, and the `$OLDPWD`.

Additionally, this would be a good feature to include as a function in your code, rather than a script. Bash shell likes functions, and they make life easier.

Finally, if someone supplies a non-number as an argument, it will do odd things.

I played with your code, and came up with:

```
up () {
    local count=$1
    if [ -z "$count" ]; then
        cd ..
        return
    fi

    test "$count" -eq "$count" || return 1

    local todir=""
    for i in `seq 1 $count`;
    do
      todir="../$todir"
    done
    cd $todir
}
```

The features of the above code I like are:

- it is a function of the shell, so there's no additional script called.
- it checks the value is a number, by doing a numeric comparison on the value: `test "$count" -eq "$count"` (That will throw an error if the inputs are not integers)
- it only does a single 'cd', so things like `cd -` still work.

I would add that to my ~/.bashrc file, or source it in to my current shell.

Answer (score 11):

200_success's answer uses the evil `eval` which in his context was unnecessary.

**Update**: Oh, what, [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)? Let's use some brace expansion + evil things:

```
# This time we have to be evil. All code in this answer is CC0.
up() { [ "$1" -eq "$1" ] &>/dev/null || set -- 1; "cd \$(printf '../%.s' {1..$1})"; }
```

---

`local` is not a that nice solution since POSIX doesn't contain `local`. After some searching, I found out that it's possible to [use printf to duplicate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349842/3770260). After replacing the brace expansion with `seq`, here is what I got:

```
up() { cd "$(printf '../%.s' $(seq 1 $1))"; }
```

P.S.: The use of `seq` for simple looping is sometimes considered harmful, especially when used with `for var in`. To make you feel less guilty:

```
# integer seq, @copyright CC0.
iseq() (
    : ${iseq_fmt='%s\n'}
    case "$#" in
        (1)  i=1  last=$1 incr=1;;
        (2)  i=$1 last=$2 incr=1;;
        (3)  i=$1 last=$3 incr=$2;;
        (*)  return 2;;
    esac
    [ "$i" -eq "$i" ] && [ "$incr" -eq "$incr" ] && [ "$last" -eq "$last" ] || return 2
    while [ "$i" -le "$last" ]; do
        printf "$iseq_fmt" "$i"
        : $((i = i + incr))
    done
)
```

Comment: In my solution, `i` is scoped to a subshell. The prior value of `$i` has no influence on the execution, nor does the execution alter the value of `$i` in the main shell.

Comment: @200_success Oh right, command substitution.

Comment: @200_success But you still don't need that `eval` actually.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to forward any options passed to `cd`, particularly `-L`, `-P`, `-e` and `-@`.  Luckily, none of those take any arguments, so it's straightforward to catch them:

```
up() {
    local options=()
    for i in "$@"
    do
        case "$i" in
          -*) options+=("$i") ;;
          [1-9]*)
             test "$i" -eq "$i" &&
             cd "${options[@]}" $(perl -e "print'../'x$i;")
             return ;;
        esac
    done

    # If we got here, there were no non-option arguments
    cd "${options[@]}" ..
}
```

I might name it `..` rather than `up`.

Comment: Do you want `[1-9]*` or `([1-9][0-9]*)?`? If you typed `up 10` what would happen?

Comment: I'm confusing them with regexes. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: Er, yes, I meant regexps - sorry for the confusion.  Anyway, `10` matches (I tested it).

Comment: What happens if you type `up 1P`?

Comment: Then the `test "$i" -eq "$i"` fails and nothing happens (it would be nicer if it gave the user an error message; that's an exercise for the reader)