# Bash function to dynamically move N directories above the current directory

Tags: bash

- up moves N directories above the current directory (executes "cd ..""
  N times)
- When executed without input values it moves only one
  directory above the current directory
- When executed with input
  values, up uses the first input value (checking to see if it is a
  positive integer)to move above the current directory the specified
  number of directories

```bsh
up() {
    if [ -z "$1" ]
        then 
            eval "cd .."
    else
        if [ "$1" -eq "$1" ]
            then
                if [ "$1" -gt "0" ]
                    then
                        for i in `seq 1 $1`;
                        do
                            eval "cd .."
                        done 
                            eval "pwd"
                else
                    echo "First argument is not a positive integer"
                fi
        else
            echo "First argument is not an integer"
        fi
    fi
}
```

I did consider building a `cd ../../..` etc., chain which would execute after the `for` loop builds the required string and would also preserve the usefulness of `cd -` but this version was slightly cleaner.

The `[ "$1" -eq "$1" ]` thing is [one way to check if a value is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19116862/5225575).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing this as a shell function, then you don't need to `eval`.

The indentation could be done more idiomatically.  By using `elif`, you can eliminate one level of indentation and make the code structure clearer.

```
up() {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then 
        cd ..
    elif [ "$1" -eq "$1" ]; then
        if [ "$1" -lt 0 ]; then
            echo "First argument is not a positive integer"
        else
            for i in `seq 1 $1`; do
                cd ..
            done
            pwd
        fi
    else
        echo "First argument is not an integer"
    fi
}
```

Your question is very similar to [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/108707/9357).  The main problem, as you have already noted in your own comment, is that by doing multiple `cd ..` in sequence instead of one `cd ../../..`, you would be inserting many hops into the directory history.  Then, `cd -` or referencing `$OLDPWD` wouldn't work as expected.